# Integration yii modules in codeigniter application

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, yii, yii-extensions

i am working on a CMS developed in Codeigniter with an Email Marketing module, i have an email marketing module with required features in yii framework already...
i want to integrate these features into my codeigniter CMS

Yii Application has different features like

- Create and Manage user lists
- Create Email Campaigns

i want to integrate in my codeigniter application

any one can help in this regard

from where to start and what mechanism can be used to integrate these two application features.

any help would be appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible because codeigniter is it's own frame work. There are some on git hub that might be use full for email marketing.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is impossible, but I have not tried this. Have a look at this WIKI page to see if it helps -> http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/37/integrating-with-other-frameworks/